# bootstrap: display radio button in center of words

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the radio button in center of two words but, it is not working as expected.

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/2/

**HTML:**

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    Search by 
    <input type="radio" name="accountsearch" value="name">
    Lastname, Firstname
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="accountsearch" value="email">
    Email
</label>
```

**Issue:**

The word 'by' is getting hidden under radio button.

[image]

If I move the "Search by" text outside of label, then the text and radio button are not aligning in straight line.

[image]

How should I fix this issue? My preference is a solution without custom css.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/4/) what you're looking for?

You have a negative margin and absolute positioning on the radio button:

```
.radio-inline input[type=radio] { 
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

The quickest way to resolve this while still maintaining the inline display, and doing no custom overrides as you mentioned, would probably just be to separate your first label from your second:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    Search by
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="accountsearch" value="name">
    Lastname, Firstname
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="accountsearch" value="email">
    Email
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap rules are giving the radio button two styles you may not want:

```
.radio-inline input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

You can override these rules with this:

```
input[type=radio] {
  position: relative !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebwwvy6m/5/

Comment: I believe this solution is more along the lines of how I would resolve the issue, although it's worth noting that OP specifically stated "My preference is a solution without custom CSS."

Comment: @Santi, thanks for the feedback. That part of the question was added after I posted my answer.

Comment: Oh, woops! I wouldn't have pointed it out had I noticed it was added in an edit. Sorry bud!

Comment: @Santi, yeah I had already left the page. OP probably added that *because* of my answer :-)